# How to validate AWS Service belonging to an arn during terraform plan using Open Policy Agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, open-policy-agent

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "sns" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.console.name
  target_id = "SendToSNS"
  arn       = aws_sns_topic.aws_logins.arn
}
```

I would like to use `Open Policy Agent` to ensure the arn of the target above belongs to an allowed list of AWS services (like Lambda, SQS, SNS etc).

How can i verify this using OPA?

I can check if arn starts with `aws::sns::` but the arn would be generated only at runtime during `terraform apply` and at plan time during `terraform plan`.

So how can i verify the arn during plan?

Answer (score 0):

The common way of working with OPA and Terraform is to write policy that is run against the JSON represenation of `terraform plan` (and not the `.tf` files themselves), so that should not be a problem:

```sh
terraform plan -out tfplan.binary
terraform show -json tfplan.binary > tfplan.json
```

You'll now have a `tfplan.json` that will represent the planned changes in JSON format, and will include any values resolved at the time the plan was made. You can now run e.g.

```sh
opa eval --input tfplan.json --data policy.rego data.policy.allow
```

To run the policy stored in the `policy.rego` file against the input provided in the Terraform plan, querying the `allow` rule in the `policy` package (as a simple example).

I wrote an [introduction](https://blog.styra.com/blog/policy-based-infrastructure-guardrails-with-terraform-and-opa) to using OPA for Terraform policy some time back, covering this topic and a few others useful for getting started.

Comment: Appreciate the answer but this quite doesn't answer my question.

Comment: How so? Your question was "How can i verify this using OPA?", which is what I answered.